# ReadInt16 in C# returns something different than what writeShort in Java wrote

Tags: c#, java, short

I'm writing a short to a file, using the following code in **Java**:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\myFile.bin", "rw");
file.writeShort(11734);
file.close();
```

When I read it back in Java, I get the same (11734) number back. However, when I read the number in **C#** using the following code:

```
string p = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\myFile.bin";
short s = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(p)).ReadInt16();
```

The variable *s* contains *-10707*.

How can this happen, and is there a way to retrieve the number I wrote to a file in Java, in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigEndian/LittleEndian problem. see below

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)11734);
var s = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] {b[1],b[0] }, 0);
```

s will be -10707

You can use `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` to convert from one form to another.

```
var sh1 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)11734); //-10707
var sh2 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)-10707); //11734
```

You can also crete your own BinaryReader

```
public class MyBinaryReader : BinaryReader
{
    public MyBinaryReader(Stream s)  : base(s)
    {
    }

    public override short ReadInt16()
    {
        return IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(base.ReadInt16());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going with creating my own BinaryReader!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is an endianness problem.

My [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) library includes `EndianBinaryReader` and `EndianBitConverter` which let you use the familiar API but with the flexibility of specifying the endianness:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MiscUtil.Conversion;
using MiscUtil.IO;

static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("myfile.bin"))
        {
            var converter = new BigEndianBitConverter();
            var reader = new EndianBinaryReader(converter, stream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt16());
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your library suggestion and sample, very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Take note that in Java you also have the option to employ a `ByteBuffer.allocate(size).order(LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer()`.

Answer (score 0):

your byte order is wrong

```
 11734 = 2DD6
-10707 = D62D
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

Java always uses network-order (aka big-endian) when it writes out shorts, ints and longs. My guess is that C# reads it little-endian.

Comment: The answer to "by default?" is no, there's no way to override the behaviour, though it can be a good idea to have a wrapper on the reader and writer that flips on every call.

Comment: @JonHanna The big question is: does C# (or the CLR) specify that it should be little-endian, or is it platform dependent (eg what will happen when a Mono implementation runs on a big-endian platform)? In the Java specification they explicitly chose network-order.

Comment: It's spec'd as little-endian. Yeah things spec'd as implementation-dependant are horrible, especially as one impl might go with LE on BE to be close to what people except, another won't and it becomes harder still to know what's correct; if I'm not so low down that I'm building IP packets myself, I want the spec to pick an order and document it, so while having to flip in this case is a nuisance for the OP at least they know they always have to flip.